# Biopython Iteration over FASTA doesnt work?

Tags: python

Im a newbie in the field of programming and Im trying to grasp the structure and the logic behind python loops. Could someone please explain to me, why this thing doesnt work:

```
from Bio.SeqUtils import GC
from Bio import SeqIO
i = 0
record = SeqIO.read(open("group_%d.fasta"), "fasta")% i
for x in record.seq:
    print GC(record.seq)
    i+=1
```

The above code produces the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'group_%d.fasta')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have the string formatting a little wrong.

This:

```
record = SeqIO.read(open("group_%d.fasta"), "fasta")% i
```

Should be:

```
record = SeqIO.read(open("group_%d.fasta" % i), "fasta")
```

I would move that thing inside a `with` statement to make sure that the file is actually closed correctly.

```
with open("group_%d.fasta" % i, "r") as fasta:
    record = SeqIO.read(fasta, "fasta")
```

Comment: thank you very much, I actually tried something similar but not exactly this, it actually works! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
record = SeqIO.read(open("group_%d.fasta"), "fasta")% i
```

doesn't do things in the order you think. The very first thing it tries is:

```
open("group_%d.fasta")
```

Which fails with the error you see. You need to move the format arguments inside the parentheses:

```
record = SeqIO.read(open("group_%d.fasta" % i), "fasta")
```

or, better, switch to more modern `str.format`:

```
record = SeqIO.read(open("group_{0:d}fasta".format(i)), "fasta")
```

which makes it clearer where the formatting argument should go.